# Existence of probability events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> Let P be a measure of probability in a sample space S. Can there be events A and B such that $P (A | B) = \frac{1}{3}$, $P (B | A) = \frac{1}{10}$ and $P (B) =\frac{1}{2}$ ?

My attempt has been to make a system of equations with the conditioned probability equation and see if this has a solution, but I don't know how to interpret the condition of the intersection.
I would appreciate your help, I'm new to probability. Thank you

Comment: Since $P(B)P(A|B)=P(A)P(B|A)$, we have $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{P(A)}{10}$ which gives $P(A)=\frac{10}{6}$. Thus such events $A$ and $B$ are not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Bayes theorem would given you $P(B|A) = \frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}$

$\therefore P(A) = \frac{1/6}{1/10} = \frac{10}{6} > 1$ which is a contradiction.

So, such a scenario cannot occur.